# Как ядре получить PID из struct sk_buff?

Tags: linux, kernel

Пишу модуль ядра, перехватывающий пакеты для анализа, не могу получить из sk_buff PID или сслку на процесс породивший skb на локальном исходящем трафике.

```
    nfho->hook  = (nf_hookfn*)hfunc;        /* hook function */
    nfho->hooknum   = NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT;        /* received packets */
    nfho->pf    = PF_INET;          /* IPv4 */
    nfho->priority  = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;      /* max hook priority */
```

пробовал искать в skb->sk->sk_socket->file->f_owner.pid и skb->sk->sk_peer_pid в обоих случаях pid_nr(pid) возвращает 0.

Неужели ядро ни где не сохраняет PID процесса (либо ссылку на него) вызвавшего формирование sk_buff ?

Comment: вполне возможно, что и не сохраняет: с практической точки зрения его незачем хранить, а в то же время этот процесс мог уже давно помереть... из того что ты пробовал: `f_owner` - это тот процесс, который был указан в `fcntl(F_SETOWN)` (см. `man 2 fcntl`), а `sk_peer_pid` — это тот кто находится на противоположном конце unix-сокета (см. `SO_PEERCRED` в `man 7 unix`)

Comment: Кстати, посмотрел старый `ipt_owner` — там аналогичное делалось через перебор всех процессов... так что почти наверняка оно ни где не сохраняется...